# On error display error message FIRST and then return (MS Sql Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, try-catch

```
Begin Try
exec @sql
End Try

Begin Catch
Display error message (How to?)
return
End Catch
```

Now, on error with the exec @sql statement, I want it to display the error message first and then end the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @sql varchar(100) = 'Select 1/0'  
Begin Try  
exec(@sql) 
End Try
```

> Begin Catch
>    print 'error='+ERROR_MESSAGE()
>   return
>   End Catch

Answer (score 1):

To get the error message generated by system

```
  declare @sql varchar(100) = 'Select 1/0'  
  Begin Try  
        exec(@sql) 
  End Try  
  Begin Catch
        print ERROR_MESSAGE()
  return
```